# How to change the way Blender shows me measurement information?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, interface

[image]
Hello everybody!
I remember reading somewhere that, the Blender API that shows the measurements in the interface (see left of the gif image) is not exposed. Does this mean that there is no code that allows me to manipulate the size, position, etc, of how Blender shows me this information?

Comment: https://youtu.be/gw20OyJoWeg
Check this video it will give tou the answer in the first 45 seconds

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. but that's not what I was talking about. I mean being able to change the appearance and place where information appears, but I think there is no way to do it through the Blender API.